# How to make a slider based on Input type Range (Using HTML5 input)?

Tags: javascript, input, range, slider, nouislider

I have a code `<input id="freq" type="range" min="1" max="20000">` The form type is Range (input type="range"). How to style a **range** slider using NouiSlider? This slider changes the frequency of the signal. My code works but nothing happens when the slider is moved. If you do not connect to the input "NouiSlider" - then everything works fine.

```js
var sliderFreq = document.getElementById('sliderFreq');
noUiSlider.create(sliderFreq, {
  start: 10000,
  step: 1,
  connect: 'lower',
  range: {
    'min': 1,
    'max': 20000
  },
  format: wNumb({
    decimals: 0
  })
});

var freqInput = document.getElementById('freq');
sliderFreq.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  var freqValue = values[handle];
  freqInput.value = freqValue;
});
freqInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  sliderFreq.noUiSlider.set([this.value]);
});
```

```html
<input id="freq" type="range" min="1" max="20000">
<div id="sliderFreq"></div>
```

Comment: do you just need to add a reference to the cdn `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/15.5.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: This code has been added, including nouislider.min.css. The problem is that the slider is displayed normally, but when it is moved, nothing changes. Maybe it's because the slider only works with input numbers? I'm just new to this.

Comment: console says there is an issue with wNumb, might want to ask on the [github](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues?q=is%3Aissue+wNumb+) page